# memory usage setting

Tags: vps, memory-usage

everybody,the memory usage is too much,what can i do?

```
top - 12:54:37 up 7 days,  4:38,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks:  18 total,   2 running,  16 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1048800k total,   917424k used,   131376k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,        0k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
    1 root      15   0  2840 1364 1204 S  0.0  0.1   0:02.17 init
 1161 root      14  -4  2320  600  420 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 udevd
 1391 root      18   0 35512 1288  948 S  0.0  0.1   0:03.53 rsyslogd
 1409 root      15   0  8432 1164  700 S  0.0  0.1   0:03.87 sshd
 1416 root      18   0  3156  868  692 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 xinetd
 1423 root      18   0  8672  716  292 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 saslauthd
 1424 root      18   0  8672  488   64 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 saslauthd
 1431 root      15   0  7020 1168  616 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.99 crond
 1450 root      25   0  6236 1444 1228 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.05 sh
 3328 mysql     15   0  799m  42m 4892 S  0.0  4.1   0:02.07 mysqld
15479 root      15   0 11304 3332 2688 R  0.0  0.3   0:00.06 sshd
15482 root      15   0  6372 1688 1404 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 bash
15497 root      15   0  2536 1044  864 R  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 top
20137 www       15   0 20672  14m  864 S  0.0  1.4   0:00.87 nginx
22351 www       16   0 52324  26m 9244 S  0.0  2.6   0:13.94 php-fpm
24231 www       16   0 51928  25m 9260 S  0.0  2.5   0:13.52 php-fpm
32682 root      15   0 35832 3228  864 S  0.0  0.3   0:02.18 php-fpm
32686 root      18   0  7368 1616  888 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 nginx
```

Comment: Where is the problem? What makes you think your system uses too much memory?

Comment: Your `top` output is sorted by CPU usage which is useless as it doesn't show what processes are using the memory.

Comment: I would say this isn't even a "real question," honestly.  If your problem is too much memory use, what you should do is reduce the memory usage.  How to do that is simultaneously too broad and too environment-specific to be answerable.

Answer (score 2):

The title of this thread implies that you think there is some kind of button that just magically makes a machine use less memory. No such thing.

The first thing to do would be to see if there are any services running that you don't need, and if there are, stop them. If, after turning off everything you don't need, there is still more RAM being used than you like, then you need to either do less with the server, or add more RAM.

Comment: lol. I know there is no machine to reduce my memory usage.   just want some help.   thanks for your help